# Flexible div blocks with fixed corners

Tags: html, css

According to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689856/flexible-div-blocks) trying to make more complex blocks. The problem is the same - if extend the central block - the side not stretch to the height.

Now it looks like this http://i082.radikal.ru/1107/92/a965bbb5a124.jpg but i need like this http://s53.radikal.ru/i140/1107/bd/de5c2c648f20.jpg

**left_middle, middle_cont and right_middle** div's need to have idential auto height.

HTML:

```
<div class="block1">

        <div class="left">
            <div class="left_top"></div>
            <div class="left_middle"></div>
            <div class="left_bottom"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="middle_cont">
            <a class="vacancy_title" href="javascript:void(0);">Title</a>
            <div class="vacancy_full">
                <p>MORE TEXT</p>
                                <p>MORE TEXT</p>
                                <p>MORE TEXT</p>
                                <p>MORE TEXT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="right_top"></div>
            <div class="right_middle"></div>
            <div class="right_bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.block1,.block2 {
    width:946px;
}
.middle_cont, .left_middle,.right_middle {
    background:#ffdac0;
}
.middle_cont, .middle_cont2  {
    min-height: 46px;
    float:left;
    width:840px;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    min-width:53px;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    min-width:53px;
}
.left_top, .left_bottom, .right_top, .right_bottom {
    min-height:23px;
}
.left_top {
    background: url('/img/site001/content_blocks/left_top.png') no-repeat;
}
.left_bottom {
    background: url('/img/site001/content_blocks/left_bottom.png') no-repeat;
}
.right_top {
    background: url('/img/site001/content_blocks/right_top.png') no-repeat;
}
.right_bottom {
    background: url('/img/site001/content_blocks/right_bottom.png') no-repeat;
}
```

PS vacancy_title and vacancy_full used by JS spoiler script.

Comment: I would recommend CSS3 [-moz-,-webkit-]border-radius: squared corners should not break layout in older IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your page width is static.. this is a good way to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xtw84/1/

Edit: Actually the last box might need some float for the text or it might break in ie6

Edit2: now i realized you mentioned Flexible...... Oh well.. [How to create a dynamic box with shadow - using PNG pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570042/how-to-create-a-dynamic-box-with-shadow-using-png-pictures) this same thing applies for rounded corners as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this after the fact in javascript.

OR

You can use a 3x3 table, putting the rounded corner images in each of the corners, shade in the sides/background as appropriate, and put your content in the middle. You can even make the middle row OR column be 3 wide/high and make it look a tad slicker.

OR

You can *not* try to reinvent the wheel and instead use a well respected way of doing rounded corners such as via a jquery plugin or curvy corners: http://www.curvycorners.net

Comment: be careful, the comments at www.curvycorners.net say something about latest jQuery issues

Comment: I merely provide a couple of examples. Any highly tested way of doing rounded corners with a lot of community support is sufficient.